# How to feature-detect es6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to export a module using the ES6 syntax only if it is supported in the current runtime. The goal is to develop a library that support different module management systems.

As `export` is a keyword, something like will throw a syntax error :

```
typeof export
```

Comment: no even in ES5 `export` and `import` are reserved keywords and it raises a syntax error that can't be catched

Comment: I think you should use ES6 syntax; and distribute a version that is compiled by 6-to-5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I feature-detect ES6 generators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096064/how-can-i-feature-detect-es6-generators)

Comment: Not a duplicate because of different syntax rules (generator could be tested via eval, modules can't, afaics)

Comment: @kangax I'm curious, why wouldn't something like this work? `function supportsModules() {
  try { eval('export var x;') } catch(e) { return !(e instanceof SyntaxError) }
  return true;
}`

Comment: @joews because `eval` parses its string as _Script_ and not _Module_ (in other words, _ExportDeclaration_'s and _ImportDeclaration_'s can not be eval'd)

Comment: Got it, thanks. Without a working runtime I could not check behaviour in the "module is supported" case.

Comment: @Bergi the goal is to provide a code that works in both runtimes

Comment: Based on the spec I should be able to use check on `System.import` but it seems to not be available in current implementations like babel.js

Comment: See also [Detect ES6 module compatibility (for import)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44891421/1048572)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect ES6 import compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891421/detect-es6-import-compatibility)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
'noModule' in HTMLScriptElement.prototype
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891421/detect-es6-import-compatibility)

Answer (score 5):

### 2021 Update:

While the Loader spec seems to have stalled the dynamic import alternative has been [implemented by various runtimes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility).

Since support for modules is a prerequisite for dynamic imports the latter can be used to probe support for the former.

This doesn't rely on any DOM API specifics so it can be used in other contexts. One limitation is that it must be queried asynchronously. Another limitation is that this detection isn't compatible with `unsafe-eval` CSPs, in that case probing via `HTMLScriptElement` or the `Worker` API can be used as fallback.

```js
let supported = null;
async function modulesSupported() {
   if (supported !== null) {
      return supported;
   }

   try {
     let module = await new Function("return (async () => {return await import('data:application/javascript,export%20let%20canary%20=%201;')})")()()
     supported = module && module.canary && module.canary == 1;
   } catch(e) {
     supported = false;
   }

   return supported;
}

modulesSupported().then(r => console.log(r));
// => `true`
```

### Old answer:

[Revision 27](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#august_24_2014_draft_rev_27) of the spec had a `Reflect.Loader` API that could be used for module reflection.

While that isn't direct feature detection for the export keyword in itself, it might have been possible to load a module that uses export keywords from a data-uri and then check whether it throws parse errors or not.

But it has been removed with revision 28, with the following changelog entry:

> Removed loader pipeline and Reflect.Loader API (functionality being transferred to separate specification)

---

Thus, as far as i can tell, the spec does not seem to provide any way of feature detection at the time of writing.

In the future it might be possible with `Reflect.Loader` or its replacements.

Edit: The [loader spec](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/#loading-api) seems to be developed managed by the whatwg, but it's not yet in a state from which we could derive feature detection.

Comment: Has that future arrived yet?

Comment: If the proposal https://github.com/domenic/proposal-import-function becomes a reality ([in stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/README.md) right now) we will easily check for `typeof import === 'function'`

Comment: @krampstudio The code sugguested by your comment produces an "Uncaught SyntaxError" in Chrome. Please see my answer for a working check.

Answer (score 2):

Check for the 'noModule' attribute:

```
document.currentScript && "noModule" in document.currentScript;
```

Comment: This doesn't work since OP in general wants to check different runtimes. DOM APIs are not necessarily available, e.g. in node.js or web workers. If they were available a check would be trivial by building a `<script type='module'>` element.

Comment: @the8472 Web workers are loaded by DOM APIs, so you should know by that point whether es6 modules are supported or not. With node.js, you can just require a minimum version of node.js.