# Redefined variable not success

Tags: javascript, scope, var

For the following code, as I have redeclared `a` with `var a`, my expectation for `alert(a)` is to show `undefined`, but why it shows `4`?

```js
function f(a) {
  var a;
  alert(a);
}

f(4);
```

Comment: jslint or other linters will report an error such as "Redefinition of `a`:,

Comment: Also, if you use `let` instead of `var`, the interpreter (or transpiler) itself will produce a useful error.

Comment: Your title is quite misleading, you arent redefining variable here

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript, a variable is either *global* or *local to a function*. There is no such thing as nested scopes within a function (unless you actually nest one function inside another function).

Quoting Mozilla's JavaScript docs:

> [The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Since both the function parameter `a` and your `var a` are declared in the same function scope, they resolve to the same variable.

See also: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431)

---

Note that object fields can also sort of be considered another level of scoping—but that isn't really relevant to your question.

Also—as torazaburo points out in his comment below—[ECMAScript 6 introduced a `let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which lets you create true nested scopes within functions. However, this feature is new enough that I didn't originally consider it worth mentioning (since it's not really safe to use in production code just yet). E.g., it looks like [Firefox won't officially support the new `let` construct until their new release at the end of this month (January 2016)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/44).

Comment: *There is no such thing as nested scopes within a function* But what about `let`?

Comment: @torazaburo - Good point. However, since `let` was just standardized last year, it'll probably be a while before it's actually safe to use in the wild without [jumping through hoops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529367).

Answer (score 5):

Declarations are moved to the top of their scope in a process called hoisting.

For example:

```
var a = 5;
var a = 6;
var a;
```

becomes something like

```
var a = undefined;
a = 5;
a = 6;
a;
```

Therefore, attempting to redeclare an already declared variable without using any assignment does nothing.

In your case, the variable `a` is already declared as a parameter of the function. So `var a;` is useless. If you want to set it to undefined, use `a = void 0;`.

Comment: I don't get it--what is the relevance of hoisting here?

Comment: @torazaburo Whn a variable is declared with `var a;`, its value will be undefined. But declarations are moved to the top because of hoisting, so a variable can't be redeclared. At least that's how I understand it.